# How to slide rank and preserve its order in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like follows

```
location   rank
location_A 1
location_B 2
location_C 3
location_D 4
location_E 5
location_F 6
・
・
・
```

And, closest location = `location_E` and second scond closest location =`location_D`
so I would like to get following intermidiate table

```
location    rank
location_E  1
location_D  2
```

My desired result is as follows.`location_E` and `location_D` is moved its rank as `1` and `2` and remaining location preserve its `order` but slide its `rank`

```
location    rank
location_E  1
location_D  2
location_A  3
location_B  4
location_C  5
location_F  6
・
・
```

Are there any good way to achieve this?
thanks

Comment: Do you aim to `update` this table applying these changes, or construct a `select` with this logic? Can you show an example of how you determine proximity of these locations and in relation to what?

Comment: thank you for comment, I would like to `update` my table. location_E and location_D will be defined as arbitrary. so I set location_E and location_D as example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using `RANK` function with conditional order by clause:

```
SELECT location,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                             WHEN location = 'location_E' THEN 1
                             WHEN location = 'location_D' THEN 2
                             ELSE 3
                             END, rank_) rank_
FROM table_name
```

And if you want to update your table with the new ranks, try the following:

```
WITH ranks AS
(
  SELECT location,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                   WHEN location = 'location_E' THEN 1
                                   WHEN location = 'location_D' THEN 2
                                   ELSE 3
                                   END, rank_) rank_
  FROM table_name
)

UPDATE table_name T
SET rank_ = R.rank_
FROM ranks R
WHERE T.location = R.location;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AzQyzktd).

Answer (score 0):

Longer, but it's an `update` [you were after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426527/how-to-slide-rank-and-preserve-its-order-in-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment131412903_74426527), plus it lets you just plug in your arbitrary list of values. If you were to use `case`, each time you'd have to reconstruct it based on incoming order, either manually or through dynamic SQL.

```sql
with 
 updates(location,rank) as
(values ('location_E',1),--add arbitrarily many, not having to modify the rest of the query
        ('location_D',2) )
,intermediate_ranks as 
  (  select location,
            -'infinity'::numeric as rank1,--puts new ranks always ahead of old
            rank as rank2
     from updates
     union 
     select location,
            'infinity'::numeric as rank1,--puts old ranks always behind the new
            rank as rank2
     from locations
     where location not in (select location from updates) )
,new_ranks as
  (  select location, 
             rank() over (order by rank1,rank2) as new_rank
     from intermediate_ranks)
update  locations l
set     rank=n.new_rank
from    new_ranks n
where   l.location=n.location;
```

[Online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQVf4hDhKqAm1sGsSeV52x/1)

1. You could use an `INSERT...ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` or `MERGE` in PostgreSQL15+ to also handle adding new locations this way. Currently, you have to insert the new location first, then reorder them through a separate update.
2. [`'-infinity'::numeric` and `'infinity'::numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) could be any pair of numbers placing new rank first and old rank second (e.g. `0` and `1`) but it's fun to use a number that's by definition always lower/higher than any other.